# Xcode Navigator Control Type

Tags: cocoa, appkit

I'm trying to discern what kind of control is used in Xcode for the Navigator pane on the left hand side (see image below).

[image: Xcode Navigator Header]

Essentially, this functions as a segmented control but the style differs from the standard `NSSegmentStyle` enums.

Is this a `UISegmentedControl` subclassed to do its own drawing, or is there another type of control that could be used here instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Investigating with the [F-Script tool for Cocoa](http://www.fscript.org/), I see that this part of Xcode's UI is implemented by an instance of an [`NSMatrix`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMatrix_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with the following key observations:

- Its cells are custom classes derived from [`NSButtonCell`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSButtonCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html), presumably for custom drawing and some eventing.
- The `mode` property of the `NSMatrix` instance is set to [`NSRadioModeMatrix`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMatrix_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSRadioModeMatrix), to make sure that only one cell gets selected.